# Function returning null when trying to access table data

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a website for some data using Scrapy. I found the table using css but its returning only thread data.

Tried using xpath too but that too didn't help. Actually, the code doesn't have tbody tag because of it the function returns null.

I am trying to **scrape** this [website](https://www.blackrock.com/us/individual/products/227548/blackrock-gnmainstitutional-class-fund)

```
def parse(self, response):
        table = response.css('div.iw_component div.mobile-collapse div.fund-component div#exposureTabs div.component-tabs-panel div.table-chart-container div.fund-component table#tabsSectorDataTable')
        print(table.extract())
```

I want to access data in the selected table which is present in tbody tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you're looking for is loaded **dynamically using Javascript** that's why Scrapy can't find it. You can try to use [Scrapy-Splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) or parse it by yourself:

```
import json

def parse(self, response):
    table_json = response.xpath('//script[contains(.,  "var tabsSectorDataTable =")]/text()').re_first(r'var tabsSectorDataTable =(.+?\]);')
    table = json.loads(table_json)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked. Can you suggest any good source where I can learn more about scraping such sites?